# Genitive Help with Time

Tags: грамматика, падежи

I came across this sentence, "Уточни, пожалуйста: какого числа будем разговаривать и в какое время!" Why is the genitive being used for какого числа?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tend to see an abbreviation here: *(днём/в день) какого числа?* It's something like '*on the day of which date?*' Then, the missing Russian *day* technically 'belongs' to that *date* (чей, чего -> genitive case).